# Proving Conservativeness directly from Maharam's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

From the book Infinite ergodic theory of numbers, Kesseböhmer, proposition 2.4.27b on page 106. I'm sorry but I don't have a link.

They say it follows directly from Maharam's theorem. They probably mean that there is a sweep-out set $Y$ and measure preservingness is satisfied by part a (from the same proposition  2.4.27). But then what about the $\sigma$-finiteness? I don't think that is so trivial and 'directly from Maharam'.

From Kac's lemma it is easy, from which it follows that $m(X)<\infty$. But the proof of Kac's lemma is not trivial, so then we still don't have a direct consequence of Maharam.

Maybe they mean the $\sigma$-finiteness is already in their definition of 'system'? In the beginning of section 2.1 they only say that about 'dynamical systems'.

I hope someone can give an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already got it, so answering is not needed anymore

Comment: Can you add your answer for us?

Comment: It's on a pdf which I handed in a week ago, so it will be checked already. Do you still wanna see my answer? Is there a button with which one can post pdfs here?

Comment: I don't see an option to upload a file here.

Comment: On my website vanvreumingen.nl/Rocco, you see $\sigma$-finiteness at  the last page, problem 3b. Maybe this link works: http://www.mt-support.nl/VanVreumingen/Rocco/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ergo-hw1.pdf